# Does a local git reference repository have has any effect on subsequent git fetch after clone

Tags: git

I have a Jenkins worker node and as part of bringing the node online, we create a reference repository (our repository is few GBs). Later, as part of various builds, we use the reference repo to create clones in various jenkins workspace. These workspaces (and hence the cloned repo within it) are not always thrown away immediately after just one build is complete.  It gets reused. While reusing, git fetch operation is done to update the cloned repo within the workspace.

My question is, is there any point in keeping the reference repository up to date (by doing git fetch on reference repo itself) *if there is not going to be any git clone afterwards*. i.e., does keeping reference repo up to date help in any way during child repo's *git fetch* operation.

I'm not able to say for sure the git fetch on the cloned repository actually looks up reference repository. I feel updating reference repo is only usefull if there is going to be any further *git clone* operation using it and not usefull for *git fetch* on the child repos

Comment: Could you elaborate on _"is there any point in keeping the reference repository up to date (by doing git fetch on reference repo itself)"_. What remote repository is the reference repository fetching from?

Comment: Also, remember that `git clone` is nothing more than a streamlined `git init`, `git fetch`, and `git checkout`. If you think something is true for cloning, it's probably because it's true for fetching.